# Referencing table number as variable in pandas python

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping

Try to pass a variable inside a table reference for pd.read_html command. Extract of the code given below. Is there a workaround to assign the number dynamically?

Here want the 6th table in the webpage. There are multiple tables on the webpage
numbered 0 to 15 need to assign the table number to a variable.

```
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd

url = 'sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/other/OtherAction.do?doPmr=yes' 
yr = 2022 
mth = 1 
z=5 
payload = { 'pmrId': 'INP000000043@@INP000000043@@ASK INVESTMENT MANAGERS PRIVATE LIMITED', 'year': yr, 'month': mth} 
scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper() res = scraper.get(url, params=payload).text 

df1 = pd.read_html(res)[z]
```

The error I get is `: list indices must be integers or slices, not set`
If I do `df1 = pd.read_html(res)[5]` it works.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: saying "#This does not work" does not help in accessing the problem. What's not working? What error is it giving? What output is it giving? What is your expected output?

Comment: Also, that DOES work, provided that there is a dataframe in that index position. Which is why I'm prompting you to give more details to your issue.

Comment: There are a dataframe tables in tht position..however when i retrieve the table using a variable name say 'z' the output is blank..whereas it works perfectly works with numbers assigned

Comment: again, you need to provide more context in your question. Provide enough code to reproduce this. Like where is the part of the code that stores `res`? Again, this works perfectly fine on my end when storing a value in for z and using z to call out that index position. So unless I can see more of your code, can't do much to help you out.

Comment: ```
url = 'https://www.sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/other/OtherAction.do?doPmr=yes'
yr = 2022
mth = 1
z=5

payload = {
                         'pmrId': 'INP000000043@@INP000000043@@ASK INVESTMENT MANAGERS PRIVATE LIMITED',                                              
                        'year': yr,                                      
                        'month': mth}                                           
                scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()
                res = scraper.get(url, params=payload).text
                df1 = pd.read_html(res)[z]

Comment: Error Reason: list indices must be integers or slices, not set

Comment: Put this up in your original post. Not in the comments here.

Comment: there's also a few issues here with this. 1) you should be using a post, not a get, request. 2) the params is not your payload. Your payload is the post query. Lastly, it runs just fine. I'll put the solution below. And I edited your question. In the future, this is how you'll want your posts to look.

Comment: Thanks..appreciate the effort..will check the code and get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are getting the error of `z` being a set. You might want to add a print statement of `print(z)` right before to clearly see what's happening. Otherwise, there are some other problems with the code.

1. `'sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/other/OtherAction.do?doPmr=yes'` isn't a valid url schema. you need to have the `https://`
2. This request is with a post, not a get. The params parameter here will not be used since it is a post.

Look at the edit's below to see what you needed to fix:

```
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/other/OtherAction.do?doPmr=yes' 
yr = 2022 
mth = 1 
z=5 
payload = { 'pmrId': 'INP000000043@@INP000000043@@ASK INVESTMENT MANAGERS PRIVATE LIMITED', 'year': yr, 'month': mth} 
scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper() 
res = scraper.post(url, data=payload).text 
df1 = pd.read_html(res)[z]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df1)
                            Investment Approach  ... Assets under Management (AUM) as on last day of the month (Amount in INR crores)
                            Investment Approach  ...                                                                            Total
                             Unnamed: 0_level_2  ...                                                                            Total
0                      ASK Conviction Portfolio  ...                                             187.47                              
1             ASK Domestic Resurgence Portfolio  ...                                            1022.58                              
2         ASK Domestic Resurgence Portfolio STP  ...                                               9.39                              
3          ASK Emerging Opportunities Portfolio  ...                                             704.17                              
4         ASK Financial Opportunities Portfolio  ...                                            1009.73                              
5     ASK Financial Opportunities Portfolio STP  ...                                               7.00                              
6                          ASK Growth Portfolio  ...                                            2163.87                              
7                      ASK Growth Portfolio STP  ...                                               5.91                              
8                 ASK High Conviction Portfolio  ...                                               7.74                              
9                          ASK Hybrid Portfolio  ...                                              56.35                              
10                   ASK India A Plus Portfolio  ...                                               2.36                              
11                   ASK India Select Portfolio  ...                                            3848.58                              
12               ASK India Select Portfolio STP  ...                                              14.31                              
13                   ASK India Vision Portfolio  ...                                             313.33                              
14               ASK India Vision Portfolio STP  ...                                               7.18                              
15            ASK Indian Entrepreneur Portfolio  ...                                           17441.59                              
16        ASK Indian Entrepreneur Portfolio STP  ...                                             168.12                              
17                           ASK Life Portfolio  ...                                             149.47                              
18                          ASK Liquid Strategy  ...                                             335.53                              
19                    ASK Specialised Portfolio  ...                                             493.01                              
20                      ASK Strategic Portfolio  ...                                              82.57                              
21  Real Estate Special Opportunities Portfolio  ...                                             166.58                              
22                                        Total  ...                                           28196.85                              

[23 rows x 13 columns]
```